# how do i write this shorter jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, short

i want shorter this code but idk how

```
    var theme;

    theme = 'summer' // for set default in source code

        if (  theme == 'summer' ) {
            $('.paper').css({'background-image':'url("summer.jpg")'});
            }
        if ( theme == 'spring' ) {
            $('.paper').css({'background-image':'url("spring.jpg")'});
        }

    // and set theme when user select ..

    $('#select ul li').click(function(){

        theme = $(this).attr('class');

        if (  theme == 'summer' ) {
            $('.paper').css({'background-image':'url("summer.jpg")'});
        }
        if ( theme == 'spring' ) {
            $('.paper').css({'background-image':'url("spring.jpg")'});
        }

    });
```

this code working but i want something like this

```
    var theme;
    theme = 'summer'
    $('#select ul li').click(function(){
       theme = $(this).attr('class');
    });

    if (  theme == 'summer' ) {
        $('.paper').css({'background-image':'url("summer.jpg")'});
        }
    if ( theme == 'spring' ) {
        $('.paper').css({'background-image':'url("spring.jpg")'});
    }
```

the theme varibale was changing when user select something but doesn't change paper background-image .. :(

Comment: You are _only_ changing the variable value in your click handler now, but you are not updating anything else any more.

Comment: If you have the same code twice, put it in a function and call that.

Comment: Remove the double spacing will make it shorter

Comment: Look at what changes between the two lines of code in the `if` statement; the filename. That filename is the same as the `theme` variable. Therefore this can be one line of code if you use string concatenation. Similarly, put the repeated logic in a function and call it in the locations required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without making fundamental changes to your code, you can move the part that makes the change to its own function then call that function on startup and on click:

```
function setTheme(theme) {
    if (theme == 'summer') {
        $('.paper').css({'background-image':'url("summer.jpg")'});
    }
    if (theme == 'spring') {
        $('.paper').css({'background-image':'url("spring.jpg")'});
    }
}

$(function() { 
    // change on click
    $('#select ul li').click(function(){
        theme = $(this).attr('class');
        setTheme(theme);
    });

    // and on startup
    setTheme('summer');
});
```

There are, of course, plenty of other ways to improve your code and to reduce the code content.

One recommendation would be to use CSS to change the background-image and then add/remove classes; but I believe the intention of the question is more to do with [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) using the code in the question as an example rather than the final code to be reduced.

Comment: how about: `function setTheme(theme) { $('.paper').css({'background-image':'url(\`${theme}.jpg\`)'}); }`

Comment: TY for your help ♥ .

Answer (score 0):

This is more elaborate but also more flexible

```js
$('#select').on("click", "ul li", function(e) {
  const season = $(this).data("season")
  $(this).siblings().each(function() {
    $('.paper').removeClass($(this).data("season"));
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  })
  $('.paper').addClass(season);
  $(this).addClass("active");
})
.parent().find(".active").trigger("click");
```

```css
.paper.summer {
  background-image: url(summer.jpg);
  background-color: red;
}

.paper.spring {
  background-image: url(summer.jpg);
  background-color: green;
}

.active {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select">
  <ul>
    <li data-season="spring">Spring</li>
    <li class="active" data-season="summer">Summer</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="paper">This is some text</div>
```